# Query task + last update user in Rally App

Tags: ruby, rally

I was trying to update the Recently Changed App by adding the columns that show the last updated time and who made the update. The previous one can easily be done by adding LastUpdateDate into the query, but the later one is quite tricky to me.

I was trying to query the RevisionHistory as follow

```
queries.push({
    type:"task",
    key:"tasks",
    fetch:"WorkProduct,Name,FormattedID,ToDo,Owner,LastUpdateDate,RevisionHistory",
    query: "(LastUpdateDate > " + lastWorkDateWithoutTime + ")",
    order: "LastUpdateDate desc"
});
```

And then extract the user name that made latest change by

```
// query last update
var lastrevision = task.RevisionHistory.Revisions[0];
task.LastUpdateBy = lastrevision.User;
```

But it's not gonna work since I can't access task.RevisionHistory.Revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there you just need to make sure to change the fetch to include the Revisions as well as the RevisionHistory.

```
queries.push({
    type:"task",
    key:"tasks",
    fetch:"WorkProduct,Name,FormattedID,ToDo,Owner,LastUpdateDate,RevisionHistory, Revisions",
    query: "(LastUpdateDate > " + lastWorkDateWithoutTime + ")",
    order: "LastUpdateDate desc"
});
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, it saves my day. For the record, the extraction code should also be updated as: var lastrevision = task.RevisionHistory.Revisions[0]; task.LastUpdateBy = lastrevision.User._refObjectName;

Comment: However, I don't really understand the mechanics behind this. Query as above, it looks like "Revisions" is a part of "task" object. But then we need to access it through "RevisionHistory" of "task" object. This is confusing to me

Comment: The fetch fields are applied recursively on each subobject that is returned. So all the objects inside your requested object have that information populated. If you want to ask another SO question about it I will answer it in detail as a reference so that it is easier for people to find